# Why does chrome sometimes take my breakpoints to the end of react-dom.development.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, parceljs

When I set a `debugger` statement in my code, Chrome sometimes takes me to the correct line but sometimes instead it takes me to the end of react-dom.development.js. It's seemingly random and very frustrating.

[image]

I am using Parcel with Typescript. I have no special customizations. Here is my tsconfig, if that's even relevant. My package.json does not configure the build in any way.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: That's because sourcemaps are either inherently imprecise for minified code or there's a bug in devtools.

Comment: Im having exactly the same issues.....Have you been able to fix it ???